# Can't write to a serial port twice using Pyserial without closing and reopening the port in between writing data

Tags: python, arduino, usb, pyserial

If I open a port with Pyserial then try to write GCode to a printer controller board twice, the second command does not execute. If I close the port after the first time data is written,  then reopen it and write again, it works fine. I have found [another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030196/cant-write-multiple-times-to-same-port-pyserial) post detailing the same problem, but the solution does not apply to my code because the serial object instantiation defaults to `dsrdtr=False`. Here is my code:

```
from serial import Serial
from typing import cast
import time

serial = Serial(str('COM4'), 115200, timeout=2, writeTimeout=3) # Open port

time.sleep(1) # Wait for board to boot
serial.write(b'G00 X25\n') # Rotate stepper motor

time.sleep(2) # Wait 2 seconds or else the port will close before the motor stops rotating

serial.close()
serial.open()

time.sleep(1) # Wait for board to boot
serial.write(b'G00 X25\n') # Rotate stepper motor
```

What could explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** Problem was unrelated to software. Figured out that the endstops of my board were always triggered by using `serial.write(b'M119\n')`. Fixed by connecting the endstop in the normally closed configuration.